# How to create a Word Document using Apache POI?

Tags: apache-poi

How to create a Word Document using Apache POI?

I am developing a Resume Editor for Atlassian Confluence as Commercial Plugin.

I am sorry I had to ask this but I do not find tutorials witch can help me.

Comment: Anyone can answerd for this question?

Comment: Do you want to generate an OLE2 based .doc Word document, or the newer OOXML based .docx one?

Comment: I want generate .doc Word Doucment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your attached code file "DownloadAsMicrosoftWordDocument.java.txt" has a coding for file download functionality; no Word document creation.

As you looking for Word Document creation, please find references below:

**HWPF Reference(.doc):** POI trunk doesn't have examples as XWPF do, However POI Scratchpad has Testcases around it, please find

- [POI Scratchpad](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/scratchpad/testcases/org/apache/poi/hwpf/)
- Javadoc [HWPFDocument](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument.html)
- Javadoc [org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/package-summary.html)

**XWPF Reference(.docx):** Examples from Apache POI SVN Repo

- [SimpleDocument.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/examples/SimpleDocument.java)
- [SimpleImages.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/examples/SimpleImages.java)
- [SimpleTable.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/examples/SimpleTable.java)
- [UpdateEmbeddedDoc.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/examples/UpdateEmbeddedDoc.java)

And also refer POI [Javadocs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/package-summary.html) for XWPF (Word Document).

I hope it will provide startup for you!

Comment: @Matti Kiviharju - is above details helpful for you?

Comment: Thanks but Confluence includes POI that not include XWPF.

Comment: @MattiKiviharju - added HWPF scratchpad reference

Comment: Okay.. but I tried make .doc file but my Word says the file has some security issue.

Comment: hmm, can you please post the details of Exception or Security issue message?

Comment: Okay I can post these but then I need first to restore my code from SVN, because I deleted that source code and made my software to generated PDF-file.

Comment: these are broken links

Comment: @seinecle - POI team restructured the package, I have updated the links and removed non-working links. Thanks.

Comment: The Links are broken again as it has been restructured yet again.Latest Working Links as of 3 JAN 2021 
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/xwpf/usermodel/

Comment: links are broken again :-(

Answer (score 10):

```
package org.poi.images;

import java.io.File;   
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;   
  import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;   
  import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;   
  import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;   
  public class DocFile {   
    public void newWordDoc(String filename, String fileContent)   
         throws Exception {   
       XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();   
       XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph = document.createParagraph();   
       XWPFRun tmpRun = tmpParagraph.createRun();   
       tmpRun.setText(fileContent);   
       tmpRun.setFontSize(18);   
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\amitabh\\Pictures\\pics\\"+filename + ".doc"));   
       document.write(fos);   
       fos.close();   
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
         DocFile app = new DocFile();   
         app.newWordDoc("testfile", "Hi hw r u?");   

    }   
  }
```

Comment: Thanks from the answer. I was long time banned from Stack Overflow, because I asked too complex questions and they was too difficult to understand.