# Check if XWPFRun is highlighted

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

For Apache POI, I am reading Word documents, both doc and docx. The old CharacterRun for doc has an isHighlighted function that tells me if text is highlighted or not. Is there an equivalent function for XWPFRun for docx files?

Comment: What's wrong with [XWPFRun.isHighlighted()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#isHighlighted%28%29)? Available via the [Common CharacterRun interface](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/wp/usermodel/CharacterRun.html#isHighlighted%28%29) (You can't get the colour of the highlight in XWPF, only HWPF, as the way they handle colours is very different)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Had to do what I did in the answer I posted.

Comment: Doesn't work how? [There's a unit test for it in the POI source tree](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/TestXWPFRun.java) for example!

Comment: The function isn't part of XWPFRun. It says it is not defined.

Comment: Make sure you're using a new enough version then. I'm [seeing it on line 627 right now](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.java)!

Comment: It was added recently, so POI-3.13 does not contain it yet, you can use a trunk-build or a recently nightly build from https://builds.apache.org/job/POI/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/dist/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and analysis, I was able to figure out there is a function in the CTRPr class.

```
//p is the XWPFParagraph
for (XWPFRun pRun : p.getRuns()) {
   CTRPr ctrpr = pRun.getCTR().getRPr();
   if (ctrpr != null && ctrpr.isSetHighlight()) { 
      //This is highlighted
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello fanfavorite, I can understand what you have described, but can you share how to actually highlight the text?

Comment: Looks like you can do pRun.getCTR().addNewRPr().addNewHighlight().setVal(STHighlightColor.CYAN) for new value and pRun.getCTR().getRPr().getHighlight().setVal(STHighlightColor.CYAN) to change value. pRun being variable I used above.