# Export Word document by JSF - Primefaces?

Tags: apache-poi, doc

I have managed to export an Excel report with POI, but I want to do with Word can guide me on the parameters in the export.

My code java:

```
public void generarExcel() {
    try{
        LOGGER.info("Entro a Generar Excel de los Sistemas Asociados");
        Reporteador reporteador = new Reporteador();
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
        String ruta = servletContext.getRealPath("/");
        reporteador.generaExcelSistema("ReporteSistemas", ruta, sists);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.debug(Constante.EXECPCION_ENCONTRADA + e.toString(), e);
    }
}

------------------

public void generaExcelSistema(String nombre, String ruta, List<Sistema> sists) {
    try{
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();               
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sistema");    
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(6,6,3,5));   
        sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 1500);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 4000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(3, 9000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(4, 6000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(5, 6000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(6, 4500);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(7, 3000);
        cabeceraReportExcel(wb, sheet, ruta);           
        encabezadoColumnaSistema(wb, sheet, sists);      

        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+nombre+".xls\"");
        wb.write(externalContext.getResponseOutputStream());
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    } catch(Exception e){
        LOGGER.debug(Constante.EXECPCION_ENCONTRADA + e.toString(), e);
    }
}
```

I hope you can guide me using the HWPFDocument class.

Comment: Which part of the class do you have problem with?

Comment: Do not export the word, if you could tell me how to do it properly with something simple content.

Comment: I'm not following, sorry. You posted code for the creation of an excel document. A word document is a completely different beast, but the first google search for "apache poi word example" points out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13535394/785663) with several links to get started.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Word Document using Apache POI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507424/how-to-create-a-word-document-using-apache-poi)

Comment: The main problem is set: 

ExternalContext facesContext.getExternalContext externalContext = (); 
externalContext.setResponseContentType ("application / x-msdownload"); 
externalContext.setResponseHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = \" "+ name +" "xls \."); 
doc.write (externalContext.getResponseOutputStream ()); 
FacesContext.responseComplete ();

Comment: Hm? Can you please explain what you are trying to do and where you get stuck?

Comment: Say I have built the word in the servlet, I want now is to export it without physically creating it, that's possible.

Comment: Sure, the `HWPFDocument` class has a `write` method just like `HSSFWorkbook`. It works just like the code you already have.