# Put image in word document

Tags: java, apache, ms-word

I am trying to create a word document with `apache` poi which will contain a `jpeg` picture. I ve found code to do so from here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507424/how-to-create-a-word-document-using-apache-poi). However, when I run the code a `docx` is created, it seems with its size that contains the jpg image but I couldn't open it. 
My code is the following:

```
    import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;  
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.BreakType; 
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;


    public class SimpleImages {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();

        XWPFRun r = p.createRun();

        //for(String imgFile : args) {
        String imgFile = "mosaic.jpg";
            int format =XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG;

            r.setText(imgFile);
            r.addBreak();
            r.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), format, imgFile, Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200)); // 200x200 pixels
            r.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
        //}

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("images.docx");
        doc.write(out);
        out.close();
    }


}
```

When I tried to open my docx I am receiving:

> the file file.docx cannot be opened because there are problems with
>   the contents

.

Comment: I just have the same problem. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I think you need to use UTF.

Comment: where is doc.write(out), you are getting error because you are not writing anything to FileOutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but its got resolved. Previously i was using poi 3.10 version and that was culprit for the issue. I just updated it to 3.12 and issue got resolved