# How to save file as a word document in Android?

Tags: android

I am building an application in which I have to save text from a string to word document.

I tried to use **Apache POI library** but i wasn't able to create word file, it was only providing me objects to deal with worksheets.

Is there any others free API's to complete this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache POI should have all that you need.
As you looking for Word Document creation, please find references below:

**HWPF Reference(.doc):** POI trunk doesn't have examples as XWPF do, However POI Scratchpad has Testcases around it, please find

- [POI Scratchpad](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/scratchpad/testcases/org/apache/poi/hwpf/)
- Javadoc [HWPFDocument](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument.html)
- Javadoc [org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/package-summary.html)

**XWPF Reference(.docx):** Examples from Apache POI SVN Repo

- [SimpleDocument.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/SimpleDocument.java)
- [SimpleImages.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/SimpleImages.java)
- [SimpleTable.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/SimpleTable.java)
- [UpdateEmbeddedDoc.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/UpdateEmbeddedDoc.java)

Please refer to the following links:
[Writing Microsoft Word Documents in Java With Apache POI (Part 1 – Writing Paragraphs)](http://tkgospodinov.com/writing-microsoft-word-documents-in-java-with-apache-poi/)
[Writing Microsoft Word Documents in Java With Apache POI (Part 2 – Creating Tables)](http://tkgospodinov.com/writing-microsoft-word-documents-in-java-with-apache-poi-part-2-creating-tables/)

And also refer POI [Javadocs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/package-summary.html) for XWPF (Word Document).

Other libraries could be [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) or [java2word](http://code.google.com/p/java2word/)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13535394/738113)