# How does POI generate a word document? And dynamically add data? I did the following

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

First, I need create a file in my program, like this:

```
File file = new File(jChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath()+".docx");
if (!file.exists()) {
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

then, I need to add some information to it like this:

```
OPCPackage pack = POIXMLDocument.openPackage(path); //this path is the file's path;  
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(pack);
XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
paragraph.setAlignment(wordFont.getAlign());
XWPFRun run = paragraph.insertNewRun(paragraph.getRuns().size());
run.setText(data);
```

When I'm running it, it has the error like this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Can't open the specified file: 'C:\Users\sks\Desktop\17.docx'
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:103)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:207)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:186)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.openPackage(POIXMLDocument.java:67)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you have a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507424/how-to-create-a-word-document-using-apache-poi I'm very sure that POI doesn't like to "read" from an empty file, i.e. you'd have to tell it that if the file doesn't exist it should create the basics rather than reading them from a file (e.g. your stacktrace shows that it tries to read from a zip file which isn't a zip at all due to it being empty).

Comment: I want to write to the word file multiple times,so I have to write it by path.Just like I write a txt file, append something

Comment: Yes and that's why you need to tell POI whether it needs to create a new document or read and update an existing one.

Comment: Can you help me how to do this?

Comment: Have a look at the link I posted. There are quite a couple of examples to get you started.

Comment: Yes,I read it.But ,when I changed like this:**********************************File file = new File(path);
   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
   
   XWPFDocument doc = null;
   if(!file.exists()){
    doc = new XWPFDocument();
   }else{
    doc = new XWPFDocument(fileInputStream);
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem, just use XWPFDocument when you create it：

```
                XWPFDocument xwpfDocument = new XWPFDocument();
                File file = new  File("hello.docx");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }
                try {
                    xwpfDocument.write(new FileOutputStream(file));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```